# How to put align multiple divs that are different sizes?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently fixing an old developers code, which contains multiple sections. I'm struggling to align one of them which is really frustrating.It's really annoying as it changes as the page resizes.

This is what it looks like.

[image: This is how it looks like]

This is what I want it to look like.

[image: This is what I want]

The comment section, as implied is a comment section. Is possible to make this scroll-able when overflowing?

Comment: #commentSection {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

Comment: What are your browser requirements? Have you looked at Flexbox?

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere so we can edit the positioning? Just share a link to jsfiddle/codepen or post it in your question.

Comment: @JaredBledsoe this should be an answer not a comment, but yes that should fix it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you want scroll only on the comment section you can do this way:

```
#div1 { height: 80vh; }
#div2 { height: 20vh; }
#title { height:10vh }
#comments {height: 90vh; overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Remember to configure the width too. This was only an example only for heights.